# If more than X entries with a future date in a specific column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a university database that is getting continuously updated with new lessons.

Normally, students do learn about the lessons during the same date, but i've noticed future dates for some entries, so i am thinking of running an sql query that will analyze a specific column and if it finds more than 2 entries with future date (+1 from the current in the format of YYYY-MM-DD), it should use php mail to mail me out, else, it will echo that no future lessons are found.

I thought that this could be integrated into my PHP code with the help of an SQL query, but I am not really sure how to do that, so any help would be appreciated.

I was wondering if my current approach is correct:

```
$sql = "SELECT publisheddate FROM lessons WHERE CONVERT(char(10), GetDate() +1,126);
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows < 2) {
    echo "2 new lessons for tomorrow";
}
} else {
    echo "0 future lessons";
```

Comment: Your use of the [MySQL convert() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) is incorrect, and your PHP if/else logic doesn't match what you put in the body of those conditions.

Comment: Oops, didnt notice! Thanks for it @PatrickQ - Im updating the initial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause needs to indicate what column you are comparing your converted date to. Additionally, you would probably be better off returning a `count(*)` of the rows from the database, rather than returning all the rows to your PHP script, and having PHP count it. If you happened to have a million classes tomorrow (or if the school accidentally duplicates a class a million times in the database...), your script would have to wait to receive a million rows over the network, as opposed to a single integer.

Try an SQL statement like this (you've indicated that `publisheddate` is a `date` datatype, so I won't bother converting it to a date):

```
SELECT 
    count(*) 
FROM 
    lessons 
WHERE 
    publisheddate = DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL +1 DAY)
```

This will return an integer of how many rows match that criteria, which your PHP script can work with.

Comment: Lots of thanks for your explanatory answer. Im using MySQL and publisheddate includes date in format YYYY-MM-DD - not a time.

Comment: @JohnnyBratsoni Not a problem. I'll update the answer shortly with a MySQL version.

Comment: @JohnnyBratsoni I've updated the answer with a new `WHERE` clause for MySQL.

Comment: Great. Lots of thanks! Your answer seems to be solving most of my issues. Im running into a last one, which is the fact that this is a wordpress website and $wpdb->last_result which gets the last result of the query used by $wpdb->get_results that I used for this SELECT statement, is returning an array that Im not able to check its number. Any ideas? Executing SQL query returns count 3, but echoing echo $wpdb->last_result, returns 'Array'

Comment: NVM, solved this with: $num = $wpdb->get_var($count_query)

Comment: @JohnnyBratsoni Glad to hear you got it resolved! As you found out, the query does return a single value, but that value is still treated as a result set (of one row with one column), and is thus stored in an array.